# Slight delay when clicking a button

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I just made simple app using JodaTime libary. It does nothing special, only calculates difference in time ( 24hour time ) and outputs that on the screen. For example difference between hour 21 and 03 is 6 hours. Nothing special and app works.

But i have a problem. When i click "calculate" button i experience some unusual delay. Its like when i click button it takes 3 seconds to "calculate" on emulator. On my phone it takes like half of second. But you can see that calculating is not instant. But when i want to calculate the second time, then it does instant with no problem. On actual phone and emulator. Can someone tell me what could be wrong? Here is my onClick code (in activity i have only references to views ). As far as i know it should be problem with objects..loading into memory? Because when they are exists in memory there is no delay. How can i improve my code so there won't be any delay anymore?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View ClickedView) {

    hour1 = Integer.parseInt(field_hour1.getText().toString());
    hour2 = Integer.parseInt(field_hour2.getText().toString());



    if(hour2 < hour1) {

        dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 10, hour1, 00);
        dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 10+1, hour2, 00);
        diff = Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2);


    } else {
        dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 10, hour1, 00);
        dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 10, hour2, 00);
        diff = Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2);

        }


    result.setText(""+diff.getHours());}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
public static int diff(int hour1, int hour2) {
    if(hour2 < hour1) {
        hour2 += 24;
    }
    return hour2 - hour1;
}
```